# How could I format postal code for different countries in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to handle the zip code of the US, (CA and MX). If the given zip code format matches, just return the object, else format the zip code. Here is the function I came up with, it falls into the if statement if the given zip is formatted already, but in the else statement, it doesn't format the zip as how I want it to be.

```
$countryCode = "US";
$zip = "123456789";

$zipRegex = array(
    "US" => "/^[0-9]{5}(?:-[0-9]{4})?$/i",
    "CA" => "/^([ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]\d[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ])\ {0,1}(\d[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ]\d)$/i",
    "MX" => "/\d{5}/i"
);
 

if (array_key_exists($countryCode, $zipRegex))
{
    if (preg_match($zipRegex[$countryCode], $zip)) {
        echo "No need formatting for ". $zip;
    } else {
        echo "Formatted as ". preg_replace($zipRegex[$countryCode], "$1-$2", $zip);
        echo PHP_EOL;
        // echo "Formatted as ". sprintf("%s-%s", substr($zip, 0, 5), substr($zip, -4));
    }
}

// Output: Formatted as 123456789
```

I think it's something to do with using the same regex for `preg_match()` and `preg_replace()` and I need to use a different regex for each function but it will make code so much dirty. Same for using substring because I need to write a different `substr()` format for each zip code.
For example:

```
$zipRegex = array(
    "US" => ["replacement_regex" => "/^(\d{5})(?:(\d{4}))/i",
             "matching_regex" => "/^(\d{5})(?:([-]\d{4}))/i"],
    "CA" => "/^([ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]\d[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ])\ {0,1}(\d[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ]\d)$/i",
    "MX" => "/\d{5}/i"
);
```

How can I make my first code to work which is much cleaner?

Thank you!

Comment: Why match and then replace?  Just format it how you want it whether its already formatted or not?  Give an example of each format.

Comment: something like this:
```$countryCode = "US";
$zip = "12345-6789";

$zipRegex = array(
 "US" => "/^(\d{5})(?:(\d{4}))/i",
);
 

if (array_key_exists($countryCode, $zipRegex))
{
    echo "Formatted as ". preg_replace($zipRegex[$countryCode], "$1-$2", $zip);
}```

Comment: The pattern matches, or it does not. When you are in the else, reusing the pattern that did not match in the first place will not work. You can create a pattern for the possible not correct formats, and then do the reformatting.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you need a model for a bad zip code to correct it.  One possibility (at least for US addresses) is to use the [USPS Web tools](https://www.usps.com/business/web-tools-apis/address-information-api.htm) to help you correct addresses and zip codes.  If you are convinced you have the nine digits with just notational errors, I would suggest:

```
$zipnum = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $zip);
$newzip = substr($zipnum, 0, 5) . '-' . substr($zipnum, 5);
```

You can use a similar approach for the Canadian postal codes as well.